# pass variable into html view angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this code in my angular js controller .

```
angular.module('IpadAppApp')
    .controller('Mortgage_LoanCtrl', function ($location, $scope, $http, $modal, $sce) {

    var host = 'http://localhost:3000';
    var applicantID;

    $scope.submit_info = function(size) {
    $http.post(url, data, { withCredentials: true, headers: { 'Accept': 'application/javascript', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'} })
      .success(function (caseID) {
            var modalInstanceSubmit = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/mortgage_loan/home_loan_thank_you.html',
                controller: 'Mortgage_LoanCtrl',
                size: size      
                });
                applicantID = caseID;       
        })
  };

   $scope.thank_you_page = function(thank_you_page_data) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(thank_you_page_data);
    };
```

I want to pass the applicantID into my html page

```
<div class="ls-case-id"> Your case ID is:  {{applicantID}} </div>
```

But it is not passing any data i then tried

In my home_loan_thank_you.html

```
<p ng-bind-html='thank_you_page(bodyinfo)'></p>
```

Also passing empty data. So how do i pass applicantID to view or how can i delcare global variables in angularjs controller. I have tried the option of putting above my module or controller declaration and also not putting var in front of the variable name but all to no avail works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you require variable applicantID to bind with html. In order to bind the variable with html, you should use $scope. So instead of declaring var applicantID ,declare it as a scope variable like **$scope.applicantID** which will bind the applicantID data to the html

Comment: can u provide your code in jsFiddle, so that it would be easy and clear for me to check why it is not working.